# Oracle: What permissions do I need to grant on a sequence?

Tags: oracle, security, sequences

I have a new sequence in my database.

What permissions do I need to grant to my web user in order for the sequence to be used?  I tried granting select on the sequence, but the web user still can't seem to see it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think "select" should be sufficient.  Is your query correctly qualifying the schema that the sequence exists in?

```
select someschema.somesequence.nextval from dual;
```

Comment: d'oh!  Missing the someschema. Thanks.

Comment: Please consider using synonyms in the web user schema (create synonym somesequence for someschema.somesequence). It provides some decoupling from the sequence owner's schema name.

Comment: You can only do a grant on a sequence with select or alter.

Comment: What will be the grant query?

Answer (score -2):

```
GRANT SELECT, ALTER ON SOMESCHEMA.SQ_SOMESEQUENCE TO OTHERSCHEMA WITH GRANT OPTION;
```